# Giving files the option to be opened with a python-coded application

Tags: python, file, ide, file-handling, text-editor

I am currently working on coding a Python IDE in Python. I have set up my program to be able to open files when the user clicks on the 'open' button in my 'file' menu. This allows the user to edit files once they have opened the IDE program.
However, I am wondering if it is possible to give python and text files the option to "open with" or "edit with" my application when they are right clicked in file explorer instead of from my program.

I hope this question makes sense; it is quite difficult to phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. The function "open with" is managed by the OS so you can not change this setting without run some code before or asking the user to modify this setting before.

Comment: Ah that's annoying to hear; thanks for your help anyway.